# Angular 2 and typescript argument of type response is not assignable

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have an angular service with a value that is defined as:

```
private client_comments  = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

I am attempting to set the value with the response from an http call, but I see:

> Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Response'

...and my call looks like:

```
this.http.get(final_url, o).subscribe( comments => {
  this.client_comments.next(comments)
})
```

How am I supposed to set the type on the response so that it knows it will be an array?

Comment: wish I knew why this was getting downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.client_comments.next(comments.json() as YourType[])
```

You should also set up your subject so it is typed as `YourType[]` too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@angular/http` package (**deprecated**), https://angular.io/api/http/Http

Use it like so:

```
this.http.get(final_url, o)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe( comments: any[] => {
        this.client_comments.next(comments)
    });
```

If you are using `@angular/common/http` package (**which is the recommended package**), https://angular.io/guide/http

Use it like so:

```
this.http.get<any[]>(final_url, o)
    .subscribe( comments: any[] => {
        this.client_comments.next(comments)
    });
```